# How can I upgrade Ubuntu LTS to the next one offline?

Tags: upgrade

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer and I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04. 
I do not have internet at home, so I need to do the upgrade offline. 
On openSUSE there a way to make the upgrade offline simple and effective way is by using  the iso DVD. 
My question is: Is there any way to make Ubuntu upgrade offline as in openSUSE ?

Comment: As far as I can remember, ubuntu ISO does have such option. But I never tried for LTS to LTS. In such case most possibly need to wait for point release (14.04.1). [I may be wrong, correct me if so]

Comment: you don't want a fresh Ubuntu install?

Comment: hey @rusty thanks for answer, but I have certain apps and files, that i need to keep and don't have a portable HD

Answer (score 12):

Canonical doesn't provide alternate-cd since 12.10, so an upgrade through the installation disk won't be available.

The solution would be to create an *offline mirror* of the ubuntu package repositories [[1]](http://www.packtpub.com/article/create-local-ubuntu-repository-using-apt-mirror-apt-cacher). Once you have one, you can follow this procedure :

- `update-manager` and `do-release-upgrade` reads the file `/etc/update-manager/meta-release` to find the location of the meta-release file. This points to the internet location `changelogs.ubuntu.com` normally. And if you just *mirror* the package repos, the meta-release file isn't included. So we need to fetch it first:

  ```
  wget http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release
  ```
- Store it, for instance on the root of the internal mirror or some other convenient location, and put the url to it in the "*URL*" value in the `/etc/update-manager/meta-release`. If you're upgrading to a LTS release, fetch the `meta-release-lts` file too and repeat the process.
- Edit the meta-release file you just downloaded and substitute the external mirror address with the *url for the internal mirror* so all package locations match up. For me this was replacing `archive.ubuntu.com` with `file:///` and the path of the internal mirror. Make sure the file is readable via *http* (or file permissions if using file access to repo).
- Run `update-manager` or `do-release-upgrade` and the upgrade should work as you were using an internet mirror.

Comment: It should be easy like the openSUSE distro. Ubuntu is suposed to be for newcomers to linux, so I don't know why this happen. I think that the big boss mr. Mark S. of Ubuntu should think about this little things that make so much difference. The difference between choosing Ubuntu or openSUSE. I will try your answer @MrVaykadji and then I will say the result!

Comment: Maybe they aren't interrested in ppl without an internet connection^^

Comment: In your answer, do i need to download any new packages from ubuntu archive ?

Comment: Well yes, you need to sync the repo, so download all the packages. But you can then move that repo and use it offline

Comment: or other way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptCdrom

Comment: that's not the same... you were asking about `do-release-upgrade`, not a simple `apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 2):

When I ran booted with the standard Ubuntu 14.04 DVD and selected the install option, I did get an option to upgrade in-place the existing Ubuntu 12.04 install. I have done such in-place upgrades using the DVD/CD media from 8 to 10 and 10 to 12.04. So I feel it would run without a hitch in the 12.04 to 14.04 case also.

Answer (score 0):

If your system is a vanilla install upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04 is easy offline using the Ubuntu 14.04 DVD. However, if your system has extra installations, it may lead to some complications during upgrade as compatible 14.04 packages will not be upgraded.

Comment: it exists an ubuntu 14.04 DVD? where ?