# 14.04.5 LTS networking broken after dist-upgrade

Tags: 14.04, networking

I recently upgrade an 14.04 Ubuntu (inspiron 640m, dell) and networking (LAN and WAN) is now broken (Network manager icon trying to connect without success).
I got some command line results:

```
➜  ~ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

➜  ~ dmesg | grep iwl
[   10.572556] iwl3945: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG/BG Network Connection
driver for Linux, in-tree:s
[   10.572560] iwl3945: Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation
[   10.572617] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have
ASPM control
[   10.627868] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 23
802.11a channels
[   10.627874] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: Detected Intel Wireless WiFi Link
3945ABG
[   10.627951] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[   10.678819] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-3945-rs'
[   29.135664] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: loaded firmware version 15.32.2.9


➜  ~ sudo modprobe iwl3945
➜  ~ dmesg | grep iwl    
[   10.572556] iwl3945: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG/BG Network Connection
driver for Linux, in-tree:s
[   10.572560] iwl3945: Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation
[   10.572617] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have
ASPM control
[   10.627868] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 23
802.11a channels
[   10.627874] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: Detected Intel Wireless WiFi Link
3945ABG
[   10.627951] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[   10.678819] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-3945-rs'
[   29.135664] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: loaded firmware version 15.32.2.9

➜  ~ lspci -nn | grep -i wireless
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG
[Golan] Network Connection [8086:4222] (rev 02)

➜  ~ cat /etc/modules | grep -i iwl

➜  ~ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:    trusty
```

Any idea about what's happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it with distribution upgrade into 16.04 ([How can I upgrade Ubuntu LTS to the next one offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440423/how-can-i-upgrade-ubuntu-lts-to-the-next-one-offline)). WAN and LAN works with new version.