# Can I install or upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 desktop without a USB stick and having only command line and no network on 16.04 installation?

Tags: command-line, system-installation, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

Quarantined in a rural area so I can't run out and get a USB stick.

Available devices:

**Lenovo laptop**

- Dvd component not working.
- Can only access ubuntu 16.04 from the terminal command screen.

**HP laptop**

- Downloaded the 20.04 on it and then transferred the file to google drive. The file is not yet downloaded on google drive.

**Android phone**

- Used it to access google drive and tethered it to my lenovo but I get the message on my Android that my lenovo can't access files on my cellphone, try reconnecting USB.

I already tried all the other advice to get my graphics back on 16.04 but none has worked. I tried the ping 8.8.8.8. code to get internet connection on my laptop but it didn't seem to connect.

Comment: You can try upgrading offline using this method: https://askubuntu.com/a/440458/20275

Comment: Do you have a Cat5 network cable? You can connect the laptops directly and send files using `netcat`: https://superuser.com/a/98323/107496

Comment: To connect directly in command line you'll have to create a `link-local` connection with `nmcli`. Something like this (untested) `nmcli c a ifname eth0 type ethernet ipv4.method link-local` where eth0 is your interface name. Read `nmcli` manual and docs.

Comment: I took the liberty of rearranging facts in your question ot make it more comprehensible, hope that's ok.

Comment: No what I used to do: create a 2 Gb partition. Store the ISO in that partition. Boot the ISO from grub.

Comment: @Rinzwind that's definitely a nice method but it may be hard or impossible to create a new partition if the system is already taking all the space, no? AFAIK he doesn't have a method of booting into a separate system on the target Lenovo laptop. So he may have to salvage the 16.04 system and upgrade it.

Comment: No not really. "parted" has a "resizepart" option to resize an existing partition.  Found an example: see #5 https://www.tecmint.com/parted-command-to-create-resize-rescue-linux-disk-partitions/ So it CAN all be done from commandline. But I do agree it is NOT the option you would choose if there is another option ;) I would just order an usb on-line :D