# problem updating/upgrading an offline ubuntu server 10.04 LTS

Tags: server, dpkg, 10.04, apt-offline

so i  need to upgrade an ubuntu server 10.04 to version 16, i know its impossible to upgrade from version 10 to 16 directly as they are more than one version apart but this is not the problem the problem is that the server has to stay offline and so i cannot use online update/upgrade.

after doing some research i found out about apt-offline but the problem is that this package has to be installed both on my online machine(ubuntu 22) and my offline machine but i just cannot install it on ubuntu 10.

what i have done is i have downloaded apt-offline and it's dependencies using

```
sudo apt-get install --download-only apt-offline
```

and i have transferred the .deb file to my ubuntu 10 machine but the problem is that when i run

```
sudo dpkg -i {package-name.deb}
```

i get the following error :

```
dpkg ununderstood data member {something}.tar.xz
```

after doing some more research i found out that this problem could be resolved by updating dpkg and i guess my online machine has downloaded a very recent version of the package so my older machine cannot parse it. so this has become sort of a chicken and egg problem, any suggestions how to solve it?

also i found out that apt-offline depends on python 3 which is not pre installed on ubuntu 10, does the deb file that i have downloaded also include python3?

Comment: There was no Ubuntu 10; and be aware the releases using the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 16) are different products to this using the *year.month* format, and you cannot upgrade from one product to a different release of a different product. Ubuntu Core 16 is a system built from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS; but 16 is *snap* package only; no `apt` or `dpkg` type of commands, which also means no user-level applications change when you upgrade (unlike say 16.04 to 18.04 where all apps upgrade). 16 & 16.04 are different systems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My recommendation would be trying this in a Virtual Machine first. Keeping an LTS release active for 7 years after its end of support, probably means that this system is mission-critical.

I found [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440423/how-can-i-upgrade-ubuntu-lts-to-the-next-one-offline) to upgrade an Ubuntu LTS version to the next LTS version offline.

So the way i would do this upgrade in a Virtual environment is,

1. Create two Virtual Machines, one with Ubuntu 10.04, one with Ubuntu 20.04(for the local mirror)
2. Create a Local mirror containing all LTS releases of Ubuntu from 10.04 to 16.04.(according to the guide, this would require at least 60 GB of storage)
3. After installing every necessary packages on the local mirror, make that offline too
4. Set Ubuntu 10.04's mirror list to the Ubuntu 20.04's local mirror, then do release upgrades step by step, so 10.04 to 12.04, then 12.04 to 14.04...
5. After making sure it fully works, using the local mirror upgrade the mission-critical Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: thank you for your answer Emre , when you say "once you downloaded all the necessary packages" does it mean the ones provided in the link under each version's description  in changelog.ubuntu.com ? also how can i point the the offline machine to my local mirror?(i mean the address format, should it be it's path to packages?)

Comment: 1. Step 3 means, after creating all the local mirrors. You can find old repos [here](https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/). 2. At the end of the guide, it shows how to point your mirror list to the local mirror. Since both of them are probably going to be on the same virtual network, you can use the IP addresses on the virtual network. Let's say offline is 192.168.122.10, and the online 192.168.122.11, it would be `deb http://192.168.122.11/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted universe multiverse`